# How to predict outcome of a new unseen example in convolution neural nets in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

Can anyone please tell how to save the trained parameters in Convolution nets to predict future unseen images.

In neural nets, we can save the parameters (Weights and Biases) and the we can run forward prop function using these saved parameters to predict. But in Conv nets, how do we do it because, we are not defining a lot of parameters ourselves but tensor flow is defining them for us?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter *how* the parameters get assigned, so long as they produce the desired prediction performance.  If you're confused about the training process (that's the generic term for a framework -- such as TensorFlow -- determining the proper values), you need to finish your preparatory research before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Convolutional networks are just another type of neural network. Even in "normal" neural networks, one doesn't typically specify weights and biases manually. Rather, they are learned through training (e.g., via backpropagation), then typically saved to a file for later use.

TensorFlow is not defining the weights and biases of your CNN for you. You are either learning them using TensorFlow or loading them from a file. If you want to save your trained TensorFlow model, the process is explained in the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

Comment: But in fully connected layer, we are not initializing any variables? So how do we get them back if we haven't named them? For eg, to specify weights for a layer we do as follows.......W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [25,12288], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1)). But in fully connected layers, we just specify their sizes.....Z1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs = X,filters=8,kernel_size=[4, 4], strides=1,padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu)

Comment: `conv2d` isn't fully connected but that's not really the issue. [Fully connected layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense) will have a default initialization if you don't specify one.